# Cross Server Domain Data Pull jQuery..Ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Is it possible to pull source data from another domain (not currently owned) using jQuery Ajax method?  If not any other method?

Trying to see if I can pull a specified `a` tag given its container (`:contains`). More specifically in the example below, I want to simply put an alert of how many 4-star ratings there are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.google.com/products/seller?hl=en&q=burkett+restaurant+equipment&zmi=basequipment.com&cmi=12986189937115136&sa=X",
        context: document.body,
        dataType: 'html',

        success: function(data){
            var fourStars = $(data).find('a[href*="rate=4"]').text();
            alert(fourStars);       
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you have to use remote json see this http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/

Comment: Create a proxy script on your server which would pull and parse the page from Google. You'd be able to pull the data from your server then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access any resource outside the current domain using jQuery `ajax` method unless you use `JSONP` or any other hack.

You can take a look at cross domain access with YQL and jQuery.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say load the page into an iframe and parse that, but google products will give the error: `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.` when you try to load it into an iframe.

You could consider using the Google Content API: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#Queries

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a direct ajax call to Google due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). However, you CAN make a php file (or other scripting file) and use it as a proxy, and then make an ajax call to your php file.

For example, make an "ajax.php" file in the same directory, containing this:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents ("http://www.google.com/products/seller?hl=en&q=burkett+restaurant+equipment&zmi=basequipment.com&cmi=12986189937115136&sa=X");
print $page;
?>
```

Then from your jQuery code, change the url to:
    url: "ajax.php",

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't do that, and for a clear reason. If you don't control the other site, all you can do is proxy the requests through your own server.

If you do control the other site, add some JSONP functionality to it (it's actually quite simple), but be careful not to give out user-specific info, since it can, obviously, be used by everyone else too.

If you actually meant Google when you said "another domain (not currently owned)" ;), they have a JSONP API - see http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html - json-in-script.